# Get file args from inside a function called with args

Tags: linux, bash, shell, posix

So here's the situation... I have shell script file which contains functions alongside other commands like...

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

myFunc() {
  for arg in "$@"; do
    # ... do something with every arg passed to myFunc
  done
}

# ... do something

myFunc func-arg-1

# ... do something

myFunc func-arg-2 func-arg-1

# ... do something
```

Is it possible to obtain the arguments passed to the file from within `myFunc`?

Comment: Yes, just call myFunc with those arguments: `myFunc "$@"`

Comment: This is tagged with [tag:bash], but also [tag:posix] and you have `sh` in the hashbang (and not `bash`). What shell do you use / can you use? Do you need to keep the args to the function (`func-arg-1` etc.) separate from the args to the whole script?

Comment: @ilkkachu I use `sh`. I can switch to bash if it is absolutely necessary but I would prefer not to. Yes, I need to keep the args to the function separate from the args to the whole script. I can't just pass `"$@"` to the function.

Comment: @ElieG. Actually, I think it might be helpful to see at least a rough sketch of the exact use case, and what the values can be, to see if some sensible workaround would be available. Or some abuse with packing the arguments to a single string to work around the lack of arrays.

Answer (score 5):

If you can use Bash/Ksh/Zsh, you can put the arguments to the script in an array and access them from within the function:

```
#!/bin/bash
args=( "$@" )
func() {
    local x
    for x in "$@"; do
        echo "$x is an argument to the function"
    done
    for x in "${args[@]}"; do
        echo "$x is an argument to the script"
    done
}
func bla
```

---

In a POSIX shell, you don't have other arrays than the single list of arguments. You could pass the script's arguments to the function manually, with some separator if you need to the tell the script arguments and the function arguments apart:

```
#!/bin/sh
delim=:::
func() {
    delim_seen=0
    for k in "$@"; do
        if [ "$k" = "$delim" ]; then
            delim_seen=1
            continue;
        elif [ "$delim_seen" = 0 ]; then
            echo "$k is an argument to the function only"
        else
            echo "$k is an argument to the script"
        fi
    done
}
func bla "$delim" "$@"
```

Of course, this will fail if the actual arguments themselves contain the delimiter string. [Stéphane's solution of explicitly passing a count](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/644402/170373) is of course better since it doesn't have that issue.

But, with either approach, getting random access to the arguments is next to impossible. That also applies to processing the two lists at the same time, even if going in order within each list. If you need to do that, I really suggest switching to some feature-richer shell, or an actual programming language (Perl, Python, whatever).

---

If the arguments your script takes are just optional switches (like `-i`, or `-k foo`), you could use `getopts` to parse them into individual variables before calling the function. Or, alternatively, if the arguments to the function are more like switches, put them in separate variables.

And, if there's some known structure in the arguments to the function, and they're known to be "nice" strings and not e.g. arbitrary filenames, you might be able to pack them in a single string, again probably using some delimiter (character) that can't appear in the values themselves. Then apply pattern matches and parameter expansions to process the lot. (Or even, heaven forbid, invoke word splitting on purpose.) It wouldn't be pretty, but could be doable, depending very much on the details.

Answer (score 3):

Inside a function, in `sh`, positional parameters (`$1`, `$2`..., `$@`, `$*`) are those of the function itself, the positional parameters of the script (or of the parent function if called from within another function) are no longer accessible.

So you'd need to pass those arguments to the function some other way.

It doesn't help that `sh` doesn't support array variables, which makes it difficult to store an arbitrary list of strings.

Beside solutions already suggested by others, you could do:

```
#! /bin/sh -

myFunc() {
  n="$(( $# - $1 - 1 ))" i=0; shift
  for arg do
    case "$i" in
      ("$n") break;;
      (0) shift "$n";; # on first pass, remove the function arguments from "$@"
    esac
    i="$(( i + 1 ))"
    # ... do something with every "$arg" passed to myFunc and with "$@"
  done
}
```

And call `myFunc` as:

```
myFunc "$#" args for myFunc "$@"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass them to the function:

```
myFunc func-arg-2 func-arg-1 "$@"
```